# How to stop StreamPlayer of IBM Watson text-to-speech

Tags: java, android, ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, watson

I am trying to use IBM Watson text-to-speech to convert text to audio output on my Android application.
Here is my dependencies

```
compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:3.5.3'
compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:android-sdk:0.2.1'
```

Here where i convert string to audio

```
new StreamPlayer().playStream(textToSpeechService.synthesize(params[0], Voice.EN_LISA).execute());
```

The problem is when i quit the activity where i play the audio, the audio keeps playing on while i want it to be stopped.

If use `android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech` i can easily use `TextToSpeech.stop()` but how to do it with IBM Watson text-to-speech?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i asked this question, the functionality doesn't exist yet, so i created github issue https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk/issues/21 and they created a pull request to solve the problem. Now we can use

```
streamPlayer.interrupt();
```

to stop StreamPlayer